# Some shapes missing Name attribute in XML

Tags: c#, xml, visio2013

I am trying to write a C# app which reads in a .vsdx file. The XML below is the page from one of my files. Only a few `Shape` elements have a `Name` and `NameU` attribute. Does anyone know why this is or how it can be fixed? All of the `Shape` elements below which do not have `Name` attributes should be `Object` lifelines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<PageContents xml:space="preserve" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/visio/2012/main">
-<Shapes>
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" Name="Object lifeline" NameU="Object lifeline" ID="1">
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" ID="6">
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" ID="11">
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" ID="16">
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" ID="21">
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" ID="26">
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" ID="31">
+<Shape Master="8" Type="Shape" Name="Message" NameU="Message" ID="36">
+<Shape Master="8" Type="Shape" ID="37">
+<Shape Master="9" Type="Shape" Name="Return Message" NameU="Return Message" ID="38">
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" Name="Object lifeline.39" NameU="Object lifeline.39" ID="39">
+<Shape Master="7" Type="Group" Name="Object lifeline.44" NameU="Object lifeline.44" ID="44">
+<Shape Master="8" Type="Shape" ID="49">
+<Shape Master="8" Type="Shape" ID="51">
+<Shape Master="9" Type="Shape" ID="52">
+<Shape Master="11" Type="Shape" Name="Activation" NameU="Activation" ID="53">
+<Shape Master="8" Type="Shape" ID="54">
```

Comment: I'm observing the same problem - not all relationships have their `NameU` group name, describing the type of the relationship...

Answer (score 0):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var elements = (from e in xDoc.Descendants("Shape")
                    where (string)e.Attribute("Name") == null
                      select e).ToList();
foreach (var item in elements)
{
    item.Add(new XAttribute("Name", "Object lifeline");
}
xDoc.Save(path);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I should have clarified though that these files are created by Visio 2013, and I need to be able to read in software design documents created in Visio.